# python how to print list of strings with double quotes

Tags: python, list, printing, delimiter, quote

I have a list i.e.

```
my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd','e','f']
```

I want to print this out in a pipe or comma delimited format, but because some of my list objects can have commas or pipes, I would like to wrap double quotes around each object when I print

i.e. the output should be

```
"a"|"b"|"c"|"d"|"e"|"f" rather than a|b|c|d|e|f
```

i can't use format on my version of python

Comment: `print('"{}"'.format(mystring))`

Answer (score 6):

Create a generator that formats each element, then unpack it and use a custom separator. If you are using Python 2, `import` the `print()` function first (this can be safely done in Python 3 as well):

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function
>>> print(*('"{}"'.format(item) for item in my_list), sep='|')
"a"|"b"|"c"|"d"|"e"|"f"
```

Comment: @shecode The answer has Python 3 syntax (`print` is a function). You can do `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of the file to get that behavior if you're using Python 2.

Comment: Fails to escape double quotes in items.

Comment: @StumpyJoePete - OP said that their objects can have commas or pipes, not that they can contain double quotes, so I don't see how that's relevant to the task at hand.

Comment: If your serialization scheme is "join things with a special character (or char sequence), and hope that that special character does not appear in any of the items", then your serialization scheme is flawed. The OP seems to have initially chosen pipes or commas, realized their items sometimes contained those, and then asked for a scheme that used both (which doesn't solve the problem).

Comment: @StumpyJoePete - Unless the elements use double quotes - which, if true, probably would've been mentioned in the question, as it mentions other characters that may appear and thus can't be used as delimiters - this does indeed solve the problem. It doesn't solve the problem you're imagining, but that's not the one I answered.

Comment: I'm just helping to improve the relative rankings of answers based on how people get here from google searches (since that's the main value of the site) :) Also, I seriously doubt there's a serious constraint that prevents OP's items from having this particular character sequence. They just mentioned that commas and pipes wouldn't work.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this yourself. You'll trip yourself trying to handle all the corner cases. (What if your fields can have double quotes in them?) Use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module instead:

```
s = StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(s, delimiter="|")
writer.writerow(["a", "b", "c", "d,", "e|", "foo\"bar"])
print i.getvalue()
```

You get:

```
a|b|c|d,|"e|"|"foo""bar"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> "|".join(['"{0}"'.format(x) for x in my_list])
"a"|"b"|"c"|"d"|"e"|"f"
```

Comment: what's your python version?

Comment: Fails to escape double quotes in items.

Comment: If your serialization scheme is "join things with a special character, and hope that that special character does not appear in any of the items", then your serialization scheme is flawed.

Comment: @StumpyJoePete The answer was for the specific question which OP posted

Comment: It sounds very much like the OP tried to use commas and then pipes, but their items ended up having those characters, so they asked how to do it with this other character sequence. If you have arbitrary strings, then this is the wrong approach. Hoping you don't have a particular sequence of characters in the future is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> print '"' + '"|"'.join(my_list) + '"'
"a"|"b"|"c"|"d"|"e"|"f"
```

Comment: Works okay, but doesn't seem very pythonic.

Comment: 1. Why is it not pythonic? 2. I suspect that It's the most efficient of the solutions given.

Comment: I tend to favor `'"{}"'.format(...)` instead of `'"' + ... + '"'`. It's not very readable to have a ton of nested/alternating quotation marks like that.

Comment: @univerio - I can buy into the notion that the .format() variant in your comment (nested quotation marks included) is marginally more readable, but are you not sacrificing performance for readability?

Comment: @Boa Usually it's not good to sacrifice readability for performance. I've yet come across a scenario where the performance difference between those two alternatives is actually measurable in my application.

Comment: Fails to escape double quotes in items.